# Generically determining arity of data types

Tags: haskell

I want to calculate the "arity" of a certain class of *data types*. Namely data-types with a single constructor and some number of fields. E.g. `data T a = T Int () String a`. The "arity" will then be the number of fields. For `T a` this will be `4`. I envisage a function with a signature something like this:

```
forall a . C a => Int
```

for some appropriate choice of `C`. I know that if I have `Generic a` for some type `a` I get `from :: a -> Rep a x`, but note that this will require a concrete value for `a` and I'm interested in calculating it statically. Is this possible somehow? I've also thought about `Typeable`, but I don't really understand the API.

Comment: You can use `Generic` at type level. You don't have to create a value of `Rep`, you can inspect its type.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. How would you implement `forall a . Generic a => Int`?

Comment: If you're just trying to avoid passing a concrete value for `a`, you can use a `Proxy` value or the `TypeApplications` extension. If you want these calculations to happen during compile-time instead of runtime, I wouldn't be surprised if GHC does that regardless during optimization, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: The problem is not at the call-site. The problem is implementing a function with that signature altogether. If I use `from` to implement that function it absolutely *must* inspect the value. Take for instance `from @(T ()) undefined` which is bottom.

Comment: Finding the arity of the constructor is quite straightforward.. e.g. calling it as `arity T` (`T` on the value level)

Comment: @luqui how do you implement `arity`? Or if you're referring to a library function, can you provide a link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use generics. Quite a few extensions are used throughout this answer, common for this variety of metaprogramming. I'll mention the first time they are used but for more details refer to other resources such as the GHC user guide ([list of extensions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html))
 or the Haskell wiki.

```
data T = T Int Bool String deriving Generic

-- Used extension: DeriveGeneric
```

The derived instance includes a type family instance for `Rep`, which constructs a *generic representation* of the type `T`. `Rep T` uses a fixed set of types found in [the `GHC.Generics` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html):

```
type Rep T = M1 D _ ((M1 C _ (K1 _ Int) :*: M1 C _ (K1 _ Bool)) :*: M1 C _ (K1 _ String))
--
-- Irrelevant details hidden in underscores.
-- There's actually a few more M1's as well
--
-- You can see the full and real details in a ghci session with this command
--   :kind! Rep T
```

## The Arity function

We will define a type-level function to inspect that structure and compute the number of fields. This is its signature:

```
type family Arity (f :: Type -> Type) :: Nat
-- If T is a type with one constructor (C x1 ... xn),
-- Arity (Rep T) is the arity n of that constructor

-- Used extensions: TypeFamilies, DataKinds
```

When it comes to generic representation, we can pretend that `TT = (Type->Type)` is like an ADT with the following constructors:

```
-- We can pretend that there is this data type TT
-- such that Arity is a function (TT -> Nat)
data TT
  = M1 Type Meta TT
  | (:+:) TT TT
  | V1
  | (:*:) TT TT
  | U1
  | K1 Type Type
```

Very (too?) brief overview. `M1` contains information such as type names (including the module and package), constructor names, whether the constructor uses record notation, strictness of fields... `V1` and `(:+:)` are used for types with zero or many constructors, so they are not relevant to us. `U1` represents nullary constructors, while `(:*:)` splits n-ary constructors, with a representation of half of the fields on either side. `K1` marks one constructor field.

We define the function `Arity` by giving it type family instances. But really, for a first understanding, ignore the `type instance` keywords and pretend `Arity` is a function defined by pattern-matching as usual.

Looking at the representation `Rep T` above, we first encounter an `M1` node, which we ignore and recursively call `Arity` on its contents.

```
type instance Arity (M1 i c f) = Arity f
```

Then we see `(:*:)` which splits a set of fields in two parts; we calculate their arities recursively and add them up.

```
type instance Arity (f :*: g) = Arity f + Arity g

-- Used extensions: TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances
```

`U1` represents nullary constructors,

```
type instance Arity U1 = 0
```

and `K1` is a single field.

```
type instance (K1 i a) = 1
```

Now, given a generic type `T` (i.e., with an instance of `Generic`), `Arity (Rep T)` is its arity, as a type-level `Nat`. In ghci, we can test it with

```
:kind! Arity (Rep T)
```

Use `GHC.TypeNats.natVal` to convert it to a `Natural` value (like `Integer`, but nonnegative).

```
-- Calculate the arity of the constructor of a generic type `a`.
-- `a` must have a single constructor.
arity :: forall a. (Generic a, KnownNat (Arity (Rep a))) => Natural
arity = natVal (Proxy @(Arity (Rep a)))

-- Used extensions:
--   ScopedTypeVariables,
--   AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications,
--   FlexibleContexts
```

We get the arity of any generic type `T` as a value `arity @T`, which can be converted using `fromIntegral :: Natural -> Integer` for example.

```
main = print (arity @T)
```

Full gist: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/10f1da354f051b2d2eb24f6aace1bf9c

Comment: Wow! This required a lot more machinery than I was thinking. I did think the answer would be in `Rep` as pointed out by @Fyodor Soikin in the comments, but since it was itself a type I couldn't figure out how to write a function like this. I suppose I should look into "Thinking with Types". I wonder if `-XDependentTypes` would make the solution more elegant somehow... Great answer!

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I used it here: https://github.com/fredefox/mysql-simple/blob/fredefox/generic-quasi/Database/MySQL/Simple/Arity.hs for this PR: https://github.com/paul-rouse/mysql-simple/pull/50

Comment: Sure, that's totally free!

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question to me in the comments, here's an example of how you can find the arity of a function.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Proxy

class Arity a where
    arityP :: Proxy a -> Int

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Arity a where
    arityP _ = 0

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Arity b => Arity (a -> b) where
    arityP f = 1 + arityP (Proxy :: Proxy b)

arity :: forall a. Arity a => a -> Int
arity _ = arityP (Proxy :: Proxy a)
```

I feel like this is fairly self-explanatory if you are comfortable with the idioms involved.  This will work well for the use case you asked about, where you are trying to find the arity of a data type/constructor.

```
ghci> arity T
4
```

Where it doesn't work is if you try to use it on a polymorphic function.

```
ghci> arity id
<interactive>:2:1: error:
• Overlapping instances for Arity a0 arising from a use of ‘arity’
  Matching instances:
    instance [overlappable] [safe] Arity a -- Defined at arity.hs:10:31
    instance [overlapping] [safe] Arity b => Arity (a -> b)
      -- Defined at arity.hs:13:30
```

This makes sense because `id` potentially has multiple arities, depending on where it is instantiated

```
id :: Int -> Int
id :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
```

Which actually increases my confidence in this approach.  Let me know how it works out.

Comment: This is not quite what I was going for. I can understand if it's not super clear what I'm aiming for. For one thing I should've named the value- and type-constructor in my example differently. Your implementation of `arity` still needs a value passed into it. I was hoping that e.g. `Typeable` would let me answer the question assuming that some type `T` belongs to the class described above, how many fields does it have. The context in which I want to use this I only have my type appearing in a positive position. So I can not pass it into another function. Only use the type-level information.

Comment: @fredefox yes i was answering your question to me in the comments.  You can get what you are looking for using [`GHC.Generics`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html).

Comment: Ah yes, you did indeed say the arity of the *constructor*.

Comment: A type might have many constructors, each of different arity. GHC doesn't know your type has only one constructor, unless you use `Generics` - see Li-yao Xia's answer. So if you want the arity of the constructor, you must supply a constructor, that is: a value, not just the datatype.